# Same VueJS code behaves differently in two different environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have project on VueJS where frontend (JS) make request to API, get data in JSON, and depending on the data received, it builds its own logic.

request look like:

```
axios
   .get(`/api/v1/resource/${this.$route.params.id}`, {
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
   })
```

Depending from environments in which JS is located, data in response has different types.

In local environments:

```
{
    "id":128, (Integer)
    "status":7001,  (Integer)
    "title":"2638-01-19_buh@ztc.com" (String)
    "is_bookmark":false (Bool)
}
```

In production:

```
{
    "id":"128", (String)
    "status":"7001",  (String)
    "title":"2638-01-19_buh@ztc.com" (String)
    "is_bookmark":"false"   (String)
}
```

API data is sent as follows:

```
{
    "id":128, (Integer)
    "status":7001,  (Integer)
    "title":"2638-01-19_buh@ztc.com" (String)
    "is_bookmark":false (Bool)
}
```

I tried to compile Vue in local and push to production app.js  file, no results.

Any ideas or hints what could be the issue?

Comment: I guess DTO's are differ from each other. In local, "status" propery mark as integer, and in your prod env mark as string. Could you please check it? or do you have any change to show us your DTOs? Btw the api return example is in local or prod?

Comment: API return example in prod. In local it look same

Comment: where can i look DTO's?

Comment: You can check it in your server-side backend service code. It's not related to the your vue code, it is related to your server side service, I think.

Comment: I could not find information about DTO`s, but I saw another version of JSON on the server, in local 1.8.5,   on server 1.2.0

Comment: Is there any difference between these two json file? Btw is your api coded in Java, .Net, nodeJs or anything else?

Comment: API on PHP (Laravel)

Comment: JSON version I saw, when enter `phpinfo();`

Comment: Im sorry that not help you too much but, If you have a chance to manupilate the api's PHP part just check the api code on the server, because I think there is no problem in your vue part, If you do not have chance to manipulate the api you have to parse the response and cast the property in proper type to solve your problem.